# AccessControlException when using Spring Security with OpenID

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, openid, spring-security

I try to implement Spring Security with OpenID in Google App Engine but I am getting a
'java.security.AccessControlException: access denied' for the
RequestURI /j_spring_openid_security_chec

It is working fine if I use '-D--enable_all_permissions=true' as VM
Argument.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ralph

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you ever figure this out for GAE?

Comment: I got a similar error with spring-security on GAE. Then I switched over to older version of spring-security i.e. 3.0.1 and the problem was solved. Please note however I was not using the OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1 - look at the exception stacktrace to try to figure out whar is going on.

Idea 2 - ask on the SpringSecurity forum and/or submit a bug report.

I'd also note that lots of Java code breaks when you run things in a Java security sandbox.  The normal use-case for SpringSecurity is to run in a J2EE container (e.g. a servlet) without sandboxing.  What you are doing sounds ... um ... different.

Comment: The issue is with Google App Engine not allowing you to create a thread. See this post from the Spring forum: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=79670

Comment: Based on the Spring forum it looks like http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject/ may be an option rather than Spring Security OpenID directly.