# Spring security openid on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security

Anyone know how to get Spring security openid on Google App Engine working?  I tried it, but there is a `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied` error.

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620823/accesscontrolexception-when-using-spring-security-with-openid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround I'm aware of is using [dyuproject](http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject/) rather than Spring Security.

Comment: This is the route I decided to go. It works great, and it is so much easier to set up than Spring Security too :).